# Chef custom resource properties

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I created a cookbook using:

```
chef generate cookbook demo
chef generate attribute default
chef generate resource package
```

**recipes\default.rb**:

```
demo_package 'Demo'
```

**resources\package.rb**:

```
property :resource_prop1, String
property :resource_prop2, String

default_action :install

load_current_value do
  puts
  puts "the current value before change for 'test_prop1': #{resource_prop1}"
  puts "the current value before change for 'test_prop2': #{resource_prop2}"
  resource_prop1 = node['demo_resource']['test_prop1']
  resource_prop2 = node['demo_resource']['test_prop2']
  puts "the current value after change for 'test_prop1': #{resource_prop1}"
  puts "the current value after change for 'test_prop2': #{resource_prop2}"
end

action :install do
    puts "the current value after load properties for 'test_prop1': #{new_resource.resource_prop1}"
    puts "the current value after load properties for 'test_prop2': #{new_resource.resource_prop2}"
end
```

**attributes\default.rb**:

```
default['demo_resource'] = {}
default['demo_resource']['test_prop1'] = 'test value 1'
default['demo_resource']['test_prop2'] = 'test value 2'
```

I expected the output to look like this:

```
the current value before change for 'test_prop1':
the current value before change for 'test_prop2':
the current value after change for 'test_prop1': test value 1
the current value after change for 'test_prop2': test value 2
the current value after load properties for 'test_prop1': test value 1
the current value after load properties for 'test_prop2': test value 2
```

but I actually got:

```
the current value before change for 'test_prop1':
the current value before change for 'test_prop2':
the current value after change for 'test_prop1': test value 1
the current value after change for 'test_prop2': test value 2
the current value after load properties for 'test_prop1': 
the current value after load properties for 'test_prop2':
```

I am trying to figure out the proper way of referencing the properties of a resource from the action block. **What am I doing wrong?**

---

**UPDATE**

I tried changing this line:

```
puts "the current value after load properties for 'test_prop1': #{new_resource.resource_prop1}"
```

into this:

```
puts "the current value after load properties for 'test_prop1': #{resource_prop1}"
```

but I got this error:

```
NameError undefined local variable or method `resource_prop1' for #<#Class:0x0000000007b51178>:0x00000000084b3680> Did you mean?  resources
```

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to workaround this issue by modifying the local_current_value block as follows:

```
load_current_value do |package|
  puts
  puts "the current value before change for 'test_prop1': #{package.resource_prop1}"
  puts "the current value before change for 'test_prop2': #{package.resource_prop2}"
  package.resource_prop1 = node['demo_resource']['test_prop1']
  package.resource_prop2 = node['demo_resource']['test_prop2']
  puts "the current value after change for 'test_prop1': #{package.resource_prop1}"
  puts "the current value after change for 'test_prop2': #{package.resource_prop2}"
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend reading "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". We don't care about your expertise; The most important thing to us is writing a well researched and asked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 objects in custom resources: `current_resource` and `new_resource`. You create the `new_resource`, when you use your custom resource in a recipe:

```
demo_package 'Demo' do
  resource_prop1 'foo'
  resource_prop2 'bar'
end
```

Inside the `load_current_value` you should be loading the current state of the resource. For example, if you are to create a file with some path and owner, then in `load_current_resource` you should get the file and its current owner, for the later check, if the resource has changed. In your current method you actually assign `current_resource.resource_prop1` and `current_resource.prop2`.

And as `new_resource` and `current_resource` are different objects, the values you set in `load_current_resource` are not passed from `current_resource` to `new_resource`.

If you need the loaded values inside action block, use `current_resource`:

```
action :install do
    puts "the current value after load properties for 'test_prop1': #{current_resource.resource_prop1}"
    puts "the current value after load properties for 'test_prop2': #{current_resource.resource_prop2}"
end
```

**Answer to Update 2**

When you are passing a parameter to `load_corrent_resource`, this parameter actually references new_resource. This is sometimes helpful, if

1. You need some values from new_resource to calculate values of the current_resource.
2. You need to calculate and assign some value of the new_resource.

There is a convention to call this parameter `desired`, like this:

```
load_current_value do |desired|
  # will assign current_resource.resource_prop1 = calculate_value(new_resource.resource_prop1)
  resource_prop1 calculate_value(desired.resource_prop1)
  [...]
  # will assign new_resource.resource_prop2
  desired.resource_prop2 some_calculation
end
```

Comment: Please see my "Update 2" is this effectively the same thing as what you are suggesting or is there a difference between a "named" block and the cuurent_resource?

Answer (score 0):

see [custom resources](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources/), in your case it should be something like

```
new_resource.resource_prop1
```